# Combining correlations

Tags: correlation

I'm not sure whether this is a question that can be analyzed statistically, but I will present it and be very interested in any feedback, whether it's an answer, or an explanation why the question can't be meaningfully asked.

Suppose there some kind of phenomenon, P1, such that standard normal deviates which are under the influence of P1 always, if there are no other influences, have a fixed correlation C1 between each pair of deviates.

Now suppose there is another phenomenon, P2, such that standard normal deviates under the influence of P2 always, if there are no other influences, have fixed correlation C2 between each pair.

Now suppose there are some pairs of deviates that fall under the influence of both P1 and P2. Is there a way to calculate the correlation, by somehow combining C1 and C2, that would result between those deviates?

If so, is there a way to extend it to handle weights for the strength of those influences, and having more than two of them?

To me, it seems intuitively sensible that there could be such phenomena, and that they could be combined to end up with specific results.

And it seems like simply computing the arithmetic average of the correlations would probably be the answer. But I'm not sure if there would be more to it than that.

It is OK if one has to make some extra assumptions for this to be calculable. Just specifying what the assumptions are would be useful for understanding.

Comment: When you say "tend to have fixed correlation" what exactly do you mean? Can you formalize this mathematically, or be very explicit in what you want the structure to be? Do you mean that the correlation between any pair in P1 is always C1, and the correlation between any pair in P2 is always C2?

Comment: David: Yes, in the absence of other influences, that is always the case. I should have been more clear and will edit my wording. So my question is, suppose there are 2 or more such influences operating at once on a given pair?

Comment: Think I must be missing the point here -- if you look at every pair, mustn't the correlation be zero?  Because you'd get each pair both ways round and the correlations would all cancel?  Or do you mean that the datapoints are generated in pairs (like we would look at with an ICC?)  But, as with David, perhaps I need a little more to understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: Phil: This must be hard to communicate about, because I'm not understanding your comment! Suppose P1 is such a strong correlation-causing phenomenon that all the deviates have exactly the same value for each measurement. Then, whatever pair of deviates you look at, the correlation will be 1. I THINK that, similarly, we could have a situation where P1 is a little less strong, and no matter what pair of deviates you look at, the correlation might be, for example, .9. I apologize of this is somehow a completely impossible question to be asking; but intuitively, it seems to me to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Writing as an answer rather than a comment for more space.

I think the issue I'm having is how P1 is "influencing" the correlation. I don't think I've ever seen that type of description before. You might need to add a substantial amount of detail to your post if I'm completely misunderstanding you. But, starting from the top,

(Pearson) Correlation is defined as

$$ \rho_{X,Y} = \frac{E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y} = \frac{E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$$

(Recall that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent then they are uncorrelated, but the converse is not true in general. In the specific case when $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normally distributed they are uncorrelated iff they are independent.)

When talking about multiple random variables we can discuss the correlation matrix. For example with three random variables, $X_1, X_2, X_3$, the correlation matrix would be

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho_{X_1,X_2} & \rho_{X_1,X_3} \\
\rho_{X_2,X_1} & 1 & \rho_{X_2,X_3} \\
\rho_{X_3,X_1} & \rho_{X_3,X_2} & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Because correlation is symmetric, so is this matrix. If $X_1 = X_2 = X_3$ then all the entries will be 1. If $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are all pairwise independent then all of the off-diagonal terms will be 0. Many combinations are possible, but we cannot fill in just any values we like and always get a well defined correlation matrix. There is a requirement that the matrix be positive semi-definite. For example, this is a valid correlation matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.707 & 0.5 \\
0.707 & 1 & 0.707 \\
0.5 & 0.707 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So is this

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.9 & 0.9 \\
0.9 & 1 & 0.9 \\
0.9 & 0.9 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is not

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0.9 & 0 \\
0.9 & 1 & 0.9 \\
0 & 0.9 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

It's perfectly possible for $\rho_{X_1,X_2} = 0.9$, or $\rho_{X_1,X_3} = 0$, or $\rho_{X_2,X_3} = 0.9$. But we can't have all three simultaneously. So there is a sort of "global" restriction on the correlations that can't be detected looking only at pairs one at a time.

Now, I haven't made any mention of other phenomenons "influencing" the $X$'s. There's been no external force affecting $X_1,X_2,X_3$ that I could add or remove. I can't think of a way do to so without creating new random variables. For example, I could consider adding new random values $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ to the $X$'s and end up with new variables $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$. These new variables would have correlations that are related to the original correlations, but also depend on the $Y$'s. There isn't anything general we could say about those new correlations without knowing how the $X$'s and $Y$'s are related to each other.

So, could you please clarify how these phenomenons influencing the random variables fit into the above definitions or point us to a reference discussing the type of relation you have in mind?

Comment: Your response above, while not a full "answer" is VERY helpful because it gives me a way of formalizing the "phenomenon" I talked about. It's really a function, in which adds another standard normal variable which is drawn from a set of correlated standard normal variables, where variables in the set have identical pairwise correlations. Each time the function is run on a different variable X, a different Y is used. Then that sum is standardized into standard normal, giving Z. Obviously this could be written with better notation, but not in a comment.

Comment: I will have to think about this more, and maybe completely rewrite my question, but I may run some simulations first.